# How to write on screen and zoom in during presentation

Tags: presentations, drawing

A year or two ago, I took a Matlab training class and the presenter had some kind of tool that let him zoom in on a portion of his desktop so that we could read his code, as well as draw on his desktop using his mouse, for example circling a window he wanted to draw our attention to. The zoom/draw tool worked really well (we all asked what tool it was) but I can't remember now. It was a Windows machine, if that helps. Any idea what this tool could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows, there is a built-in tool call [Magnifier.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Make-items-on-the-screen-appear-bigger-Magnifier)

You can change the setting to `Lens`, and it will zoom portion of the screen as you described.

In `Lens` mode, just take your mouse to wherever you want to type, start typing and the area is zoomed as the magnifier follows the mouse.

There is also a commercial tool called [Magnifying Glass Pro](http://www.workerscollection.com/wcollect/english/html/mg_pro.html) which has more options.

Comment: In addition check out http://superuser.com/questions/455043/portable-desktop-zoom-magnifier-for-windows-xp-7/455079#455079

Answer (score 3):

Aha! I have found the tool. It is called [ZoomIt](http://download.cnet.com/ZoomIt/3000-2094_4-170654.html?tag=sideBar;downloadLinks). Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: I was just about to answer this one.  Found it about 3 years ago, have used it ever since.